# Can a runner run back to their original base during a stealing base?

Tags: baseball

Can a baserunner run back to their starting base in a stealing base situation?
R1 steals legally 2B and 3B but then he wants to come back ti 1B, is legal ?

Answer (score 1):

In the scenario you describe, no. Rule 5.09(b)(10) in the MLB rules, for example, prohibits running the bases in reverse order.

Comment: This is correct, but it misses the complexity of the question.  Why can a runner not return to first base after stealing second, but they *can* return to first after touching second if there was a fly ball out on the play?

Comment: Because they did not legally advance to second in the latter scenario. There's no complexity in the question as asked (it specifically says 2nd and 3rd bases were *stolen*), though there has been a raft of questions (of varying specificity) recently, all asking variations on this theme.

Comment: That should probably be in the answer (with the rules reference) to make this a great answer.  (Also, copy/paste the actual rule plus link to it - thanks for including the rule number but given they can change over time, it's best to include the text.)